# Do I need to enable Remote Desktop Connection for it to work over Tailscale?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, tailscale

I've [enabled Remote Desktop Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) and it works fine on my local network. I want to be able to use it via Tailscale as well but it doesn't connect, using either the DNS name, IPv4 address or IPv6 address.

I saw [Secure a Windows RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) server](https://tailscale.com/kb/1095/secure-rdp-windows/) which explains how to block connections from anything other than Tailscale. This suggests no configuration is required?

I've [enabled ping](https://www.wintips.org/how-to-allow-ping-in-windows-firewall/) so that it works locally but that also fails via Tailscale, although `tailscale ping` works fine. This makes me wonder if I need to enable it for the Tailscale IP address range?

Answer (score 0):

PEBCAK. I forgot I'd set `--shields-up` on Tailscale. Turning this off and both ping and Remote Desktop Access work fine with no changes to the firewall.